# why type deduction does not work as expected?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, type-deduction

I have a small question about type deduction in C++ metaprogramming. 
There is a certain function do some action.

main.cpp

```
template<typename T> void foo(T arg) {
    // do some action on argument
    std::cout << typeid(arg).name() << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int array[100] = {0};
    std::cout << typeid(array).name() << std::endl;
    foo(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A100_i
Pi
```

Why *arg* in function *foo()* have a another data type than *array* in function *main()*?

Comment: I would say: wrong expectation. possibly good google keywords: array pointer decay.

Comment: Hundreds of questions have been posted to SO based on a misunderstanding due to arrays decaying to pointers, usually involving `sizeof`, but this one is a novel approach. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by adding a CLOSED to the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C style arrays are broken.  In particular, you cannot
have a function argument with a C style array type; if you write
a function (forgetting about templates for the moment):

```
void foo( int arg[100] );
```

the language requires the compiler to treat this as:

```
void foo( int* arg );
```

(and the `100` is just a comment—it is ignored by the
compiler).

In order to support this in the case of templates, if the
compiler is trying to match a non-reference template argument,
it will convert an array argument to a pointer, and type
deduction will result in the pointer type, not the array type.

The result is that you should never write a function (template
or otherwise) expecting a C style array (except for the second
argument of `main`, where you don't have a choice).

Since this brokeness is only present for reasons of
C compatibility, C++ doesn't follow it when references are
involved.  So:

```
template < typename T, size_t N >
void foo( T (&arg)[ N ] );
```

will work, and should give you the same results in both cases.
If you think that your function might be called with both
C style arrays and other things (e.g. std::vector), you can
overload it for both.  The version above is more specialized,
and will be preferred to the more generic version if possible.

A better solution would be to avoid C style arrays entirely, but
they are useful for static variables with initialization; it's
only with C style arrays that you can get the compiler to count
the number of elements, and define the size of the array
according to the initializer list.  And have static
initialization; `std::vector` will count the initializers at
runtime, but used as a static variable, may cause order of
initialization problems.
C style arrays and

Answer (score 6):

Actually when you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer type. So `T` is deduced to be`int*`, instead of `int[100]`.

If you want to prevent the decay, accept the parameter *by reference*.:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T & arg) //Note `&` here!
{
  // do some action on argument
   std::cout << (typeid(arg).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Now it will print what you expect, i.e `A100_i`. See [this online demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5644cefcc78fd0f42487cb49c19b8b8b).

---

**Question: Why does the array decay to pointer type when we pass *by value*?**

Answer: Because in C++ arrays (and functions) *cannot* be passed *by value*. The language doesn't allow that. Instead the language requires them to decay into pointer type when they are passed as function arguments. To prevent decay, we need to pass them as *reference*.

Comment: An even more important point, perhaps: when you define an argument to have array type, it is automatically converted to a definition of a pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh That is definitely better and more accurate. I hope the OP reads that comment as well as your answer. :-)